# I need to make this repeat with every number until 20,000

Tags: python, math

My program is meant to check every number until 20,000 and spit out all of the palindromic prime numbers. I've made a checker, but for the love of me can't seem to find out how to extend it to 20,000

```
num = int(input("what's your number?: "))
temp=num
reverseNum = 0 
while num > 0:
    lastDigit = num % 10 
    reverseNum = reverseNum*10 + lastDigit
    num = num//10 
if temp == reverseNum:
    print("the number is paliondromic")
else:
    print("the number is not paliondromic")
if temp > 1:
    for i in range(2, temp):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            print("{} is not a prime number".format(temp))
            break 
    else:
        print("{} is a prime number".format(temp))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe use a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a simple `for` loop, but I'll also make 2 suggestions:

1. Use Sieve of Eratosthenes to generate the primes, rather than a brute for check for each number.
2. Using string conversion for easier palindrome checking.

```py
n = 20000
prime = [True for i in range(n+1)] 
p = 2
while (p * p <= n):  #creating a Sieve using standard operations
    if (prime[p] == True): 
        for i in range(p * p, n+1, p): 
            prime[i] = False
    p += 1

for i in range(1, n+1):  #palindrome checking
    if prime[i] and str(i)==str(i)[::-1]:
        print(i,"is a prime palindrome")
    else:
        print(i,"is not a prime palindrome")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for temp in range(0,20000):
    num = temp
    reverseNum = 0 
    while num > 0:
        lastDigit = num % 10 
        reverseNum = reverseNum*10 + lastDigit
        num = num//10 
    if temp == reverseNum:
        print("the number is paliondromic")
    else:
        print("the number is not paliondromic")
    if temp > 1:
        for i in range(2, temp):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                print("{} is not a prime number".format(temp))
                break 
        else:
            print("{} is a prime number".format(temp))
```